# Cant delete rows from hive table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to launch this command on my hive table

```
Delete from customer where id=3;
```

And i had this error

```
FAILED: SemanticException: [Error 10294]: Attempt to do update or delete using transactiob manager that does not support these operations.
```

Who can help me please??

Comment: You can't delete from a table unless its transactional.

Answer (score 0):

You can not delete from any table in hive just like this. Thetable should be transactional.
Couple of steps has to be performed to enable this.

1. Set hive params

```
# this must be set to true. Hive uses txn manager to do DML.
SET hive.support.concurrency=true;
SET hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
# The follwoing are not required if you are using Hive 2.0
SET hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nostrict;
# required for standalone hive metastore
SET hive.compactor.initiator.on=true;
SET hive.compactor.worker.threads=1
```

2. Create table in orc format with table properties= true and having buckets(Hive 2.0).

Sample create table is -

```
CREATE TABLE db.emptrans (
 id int,
 name string)
 STORED AS ORC
 TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');
```

Pls refer to below answer for more details -

[How to do update/delete operations on non-transactional table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73729405/how-to-do-update-delete-operations-on-non-transactional-table-in-hive/73749857#73749857)