# Hive 3.X - update column in non-bucketed table with Avro file format

Tags: hive

I am using **hive-3.1.2**.

I have created a **non bucketed partitioned hive table**.

Input File Formats is **Avro**.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tbl(

  'col1' string COMMENT '',
  'col2' string COMMENT '',
  'col3' int COMMENT '',
  'col4' bigint COMMENT ''
) PARTITIONED BY (cpd_dt string, cut_no string)
 ROW FORMAT SERDE
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/user/${hiveconf:USER}/data'
TBLPROPERTIES (
'avro.schema.url'='/user/${hiveconf:USER}/schema/schema_avro.avsc');
```

I am trying to update one of the column of the table through below query:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col4='xyz' where cpd_dt='20230220' and cut_no='00' and  col1='abcd';
```

While running the update command I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10294]: Attempt to do update or delete using transaction manager that does not support these operations. (state=42000,code=10294)
```

Looking over the internet I found that I need to set some properties in order to update the table but I am not able to find the solution for my combination of hive version, non bucketed table and Avro file format.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if  you want to do ACID transformations, you need to create internal managed table in hive. And then you have to bucket the table + set it up to transactional = true. Cant to ACID on external tables. You can refer to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73729405/how-to-do-update-delete-operations-on-non-transactional-table/73749857#73749857